# Can I preload product to Woocommerce Subscriptions renewal cart?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, subscription, product

I am trying to figure out if there is a way for the server to rewrite the contents of a custom field without user or admin interaction. Can a server to insert a `value` into a `meta_key` by itself, with some kind of trigger?

```
// This is just an example of the type of if/else based on preferences
if( !empty( $_POST( $user->id, 'romance', true); { 
$product_id = 1300; 
} else {
$product_id = 0031;
```

The specifics of where the data is stored isn't as much of a concern as how a `value` could be updated. I can add a `meta_key = 'free_item'` to the subscription product line item order meta with functions.php via `wc_add_order_item_meta()` and it can be preset with a `$product->id`. I am wondering if there is a way for that value to be dynamic.

**WORKING EXAMPLE**

I am using Woocommerce Subscriptions where customers get a weekly renewal. I am wondering if there is a way to include a new free item — based on their preferences (presumably in `user_meta`) — in each renewal. From their account page, I'd like them to be able to see the item (`product_id`) and switch it out for something else.

I know how to display product based on queries, I just can figure out how to include it in the cart without a manual "Add to Cart" click.

Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Comment: I elaborated on the question — I just don't know if there is a way to rewrite the `value` of a `meta_key` through some kind of script or something.

Comment: If this is still too vague, I'll go further down the rabbit hole and post my code on jsfiddle.